# Go one activity from another activity using third layout in android

Tags: android, android-activity, layout

After clicking a button on first activity i want to go second activity. But before view second activity layout i want to show 3rd layout for specific time.

Comment: Is the 3rd layout another `Activity`?

Comment: yes....its another activity....but only for view an welcome message.

Comment: Then start the 3rd `Activity` from 1st and from there start the 2nd `Activity`

Comment: ok.
but if i make 3rd layout only layout not activity then what i have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a framelayout to your second activity layout and hide it after your specific time. You can use something like:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {               
            try {
                Thread.sleep(yourspecifictimeinmilliseconds);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    your3rdlayoutslayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });                
        }            
    }).start();
```

Comment: i have 2 activity with their layout + one extra layout.

Comment: if you dont want to put that layout to your second activity than you need to make another activity or fragment for that layout.